# SOQL query to check if campaignId is correct on Opportunity

Tags: apex, soql

I want to query on opportunity if campaignID is correct or not ,by first going to account then retrive all contacts and check if opportunity campaignid does not match any of contacts campaignmember campaignid

`

```
SELECT Id, CampaignId, AccountId
FROM Opportunity
WHERE CampaignId != null
  AND AccountId != null
  AND AccountId IN (SELECT AccountId
                    FROM Contact
                    WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId
                                 FROM CampaignMember
                                 WHERE CampaignId != Opportunity.CampaignId))
```

I tried using this but failing

Answer (score 0):

Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported

What you would probably have to do is write a small snippet of code in the anonymous window to query the results you need.

Example :

```
List<CampaignMember> cms = new List<CampaignMember>([SELECT ContactId FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId != Opportunity.CampaignId]);
    Set<Id> cmsIds = new Set<ID>();
    for(CampaignMember cm : cms){
        cmsIds.add(cm.contactID);
    }
    List<Contact> conts = new List<Contact>([Select Id,AccountID From Contact where id In :cmsIds]);
    
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<id>();
    
    for(Contact con : conts){
        accIds.add(con.AccountId);
    }
    
    List<opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT Id, CampaignId, AccountId
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE CampaignId != null
      AND AccountId != null
      AND AccountId IN :accIds]);
    
    System.debug('opps '+opps);
```

You would have to query the Id you want to use in Line 1: (Opportunity.CampaignId)
and hard code it there.

You can add System.debug() statements wherever needed to print your results.